# Limit quotient law

Tags: limits

I'm very confused about this. When finding the derivative of sine, we have

$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h}=\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}(\sin(x+h)-\sin x)}{\lim_{h\to0}h}=\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}(\sin x\cos h+\sin h\cos x-\sin x)}{\lim_{h\to0}h}=\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}(\sin x\cos h-x)+\lim_{h\to0}(\sin h\cos x)}{\lim_{h\to0}h}=\dfrac{0+\lim_{h\to0}(\sin h\cos x)}{\lim_{h\to0}h}=\cos x\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}=\cos x$

Is this proof correct? If not, why is it correct to say $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1{x^2}=\dfrac1{0}=\infty$? Please explain.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1{x^2}\ne\infty$, because the limit doesn't exist. You can only apply the limit laws when the limits exist.

Comment: It does exist. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%5E2+limit+as+x-%3E0

Comment: Oops, mistake. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotient rule can only be used when denominator's limit doesn't become zero.

> $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h}\\
> =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(\sin(x+h)-\sin x)}{h}\\
> =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(\sin x\cos h+\sin h\cos x-\sin x)}{h}\\
> =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin x(\cos h-1)+(\sin h\cos x)}{h}\\
> =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(\cos h-1)}{h}.\sin x+\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}.(\cos x)\\
> =\cos x\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}=\cos x $
>
> ---

If $\epsilon$ is any positive number, however small, then we can ﬁnd
a number $n_0$ such that $\frac1n < \epsilon$ for all values of n greater than
or equal to $n_0$
We shall say that ‘the limit of $\frac1n$ as n tends to $\infty$
is $0$’, a statement which we may express symbolically in the form:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$$

Comment: You factored incorrectly in line 4, it must be: $=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin x(\cos h-1)+(\sin h\cos x)}{h}\\$

Comment: Thanks. There's a typo in the fourth line.

Comment: how did you show $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos h -1}{h} = 0$?

Comment: @Alex That follows from $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}{h}=1$.